# How to draw the sequence diagram if two actors have the same sequence as one is child class of the other?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, uml, software-design, sequence-diagram

Since sequence diagram is behavioral, I'm not sure if we can show inheritance between both the actors. As both actors have the same sequence, so should I separately show their sequences or should I merge them (and how do I merge them)?

Comment: A point is not clear in your question, you deal with sequence diagram and you ask about actors inheritance. If actor Administrator inherits from actor User; Administrator can activate (execute) all use cases of User and you can describe you case of User without taking care of Administrator, So maybe you need to detail your question

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question the process is owned by the parent actor. If yes you only need to present it on the parent as the child automatically inherits it (unless there is a **different** way of handling this particular process).

The inheritance itself has to be shown on some other diagram (either class or use cases).

Answer (score 0):

An instance is an instance and as such each has its own lifeline. So if two objects talk to each other it does not matter that one is the (code) parent of the other. This is just a language construct, and it has no influence on the runtime. Except that if the parent dies it will also take away it's children.